# Palindrome number in java doesn't seem to make sense

Tags: java

I'm doing some exercise programs in Java and came to this palindrome number exercise which tells if the number is palindrome, I'm getting the correct output but I'm trying to explain to myself how the program is working line by line, upon reaching a specific line I noticed that that part doesn't seem to add up, here is the code:

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 252;
        if(isPalindrome(p)) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not palindrome");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        int num = x;
        int rev = 0;

        while (num != 0) {
            int rmd = num % 10;//the remainder of 252 is 2
            rev = rev * 10 + rmd;//rev which is 0 multiplied by 10 is 0 + 2 is 2
            num = num / 10;
        }
        if (x == rev) {//x = 252 and rev = 2
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

in the part: `if(x == rev)` how can it be true when 252 is not equal to 2? thanks guys..

Comment: Rev is `252` not `2`, `rev` is only 2 in the first iteration. Notice that the loop will continue multiple times since `(num = num/10) != 0` after the first iteration, etc.

Comment: `rev = rev * 10 + rmd;` is where the "magic" happens.

Comment: `rev` is 2 only the first iteration, but at the end it's 252.

Comment: I don't understand that ... you said you explain the code line by line .. then you see a `while` loop and don't care about it? Why?

Comment: my knowledge about while loop is just to check for condition much like of the if statement, anyway by reading through this comment I'm learning a lot.. thanks man..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look what happens during the loop as it goes through its iterations.

For simple programs, such as this one, a paper-and-pencil approach works fine. For more complex programs adding "debug prints" help you understand what is going on:

```
int iterationCount = 0;
while (num != 0) {
    System.out.println("Before iteration="+iterationCount+" num="+num+" rev="+rev);
    int rmd = num % 10;//the remainder of 252 is 2
    rev = rev * 10 + rmd;//rev which is 0 multiplied by 10 is 0 + 2 is 2
    num = num / 10;
    System.out.println("After iteration="+iterationCount+" num="+num+" rev="+rev);
    iterationCount++;
}
```

This [produces](http://ideone.com/fVmyHn) the following output:

```
Before iteration=0 num=252 rev=0
After iteration=0 num=25 rev=2
Before iteration=1 num=25 rev=2
After iteration=1 num=2 rev=25
Before iteration=2 num=2 rev=25
After iteration=2 num=0 rev=252
Palindrome
```

Note how `num` decreases down to zero, while `rev` grows to `252` with each iteration.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so that is also a part of the while loop, it acts as a counter, I only knew while loop just for checking a condition much more like the if statement.. thank you..

Comment: the debug prints is very useful, I didn't know that one until now, will be using that a lot especially now that I am studying.. thanks again..

Comment: @DuckStudyingJava You are welcome! Once you get comfortable with debug prints at the beginning and/or at the end of a loop iteration, look into [loop invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant), a mental equivalent of debug prints. Loop invariant technique lets you construct correct code with no debugging, because all the debugging happens in your head. Good luck learning Java!

Comment: thanks man, I just started two days ago and I have never picked any programming lessons before, that's why my head is all over the place, it's a good thing that there are sites like this with guys like you who are willing to extend a helping hand for those beginners like me..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

`rev` is 2 only on the first iteration of your `while` loop, on the second iteration it is 25 and on third iteration `rev` is 252.

```
if (x == rev) {//x = 252 and rev = 2
    return true;
}
return false;
```

this condition can also be simplified as:

```
return x == rev;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

```
while (num != 0) {
    int rmd = num % 10; // take the last digit of num
    rev = rev * 10 + rmd; // append it to rev (rev * 10 shifts to the left, and then we add)
    num = num / 10; // remove it from num
}
```

Since it repeats until `num` is zero, `rev` will end up containing the reversed `num`. Then obviously if the reversed number is the same as the original `x`, then it's a palindrome.

Well, that's at least in theory. In practice, this algorithm has a bug: reversal will may overflow for large numbers (e. g. any 10-digit number ending with 3 or greater). There is [a much better solution](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8090/9-line-accepted-java-code-without-the-need-of-handling-overflow).